# anaconda3 install error: raise Exception("dst exists: %r" % dst)

Tags: linux, cifs, azure-files, xattr, anaconda3

I am trying to install anaconda3 in a CIFS drive (Azure File Share in my case) but i keep getting this error:

```
PREFIX=/monsoondrive/central/anaconda3
installing: python-3.7.3-h0371630_0 ...

Python 3.7.3
installing: conda-env-2.6.0-1 ...
installing: blas-1.0-mkl ...
installing: ca-certificates-2019.1.23-0 ...
installing: intel-openmp-2019.3-199 ...
installing: libgcc-ng-8.2.0-hdf63c60_1 ...
installing: libgfortran-ng-7.3.0-hdf63c60_0 ...
installing: libstdcxx-ng-8.2.0-hdf63c60_1 ...
installing: bzip2-1.0.6-h14c3975_5 ...
installing: expat-2.2.6-he6710b0_0 ...
installing: fribidi-1.0.5-h7b6447c_0 ...
installing: gmp-6.1.2-h6c8ec71_1 ...
installing: graphite2-1.3.13-h23475e2_0 ...
installing: icu-58.2-h9c2bf20_1 ...
installing: jbig-2.1-hdba287a_0 ...
installing: jpeg-9b-h024ee3a_2 ...
installing: libffi-3.2.1-hd88cf55_4 ...
installing: liblief-0.9.0-h7725739_2 ...
installing: libsodium-1.0.16-h1bed415_0 ...
installing: libtool-2.4.6-h7b6447c_5 ...
installing: libuuid-1.0.3-h1bed415_2 ...
installing: libxcb-1.13-h1bed415_1 ...
installing: lz4-c-1.8.1.2-h14c3975_0 ...
installing: lzo-2.10-h49e0be7_2 ...
installing: mkl-2019.3-199 ...
installing: ncurses-6.1-he6710b0_1 ...


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/monsoondrive/central/anaconda3/pkgs/.install.py", line 599, in <module>
    main()
  File "/monsoondrive/central/anaconda3/pkgs/.install.py", line 581, in main
    link_dist(opts.link_dist)
  File "/monsoondrive/central/anaconda3/pkgs/.install.py", line 456, in link_dist
    link(prefix, dist, linktype)
  File "/monsoondrive/central/anaconda3/pkgs/.install.py", line 345, in link
    raise Exception("dst exists: %r" % dst)
Exception: dst exists: '/monsoondrive/central/anaconda3/share/terminfo/e/eterm'
```

I have been struggling with this error for a while and I can't get close to any solution.

Also this is how i am mounting the Azure File Share to my system (if this info helps):

```
sudo mount -t cifs //azure.file.core.windows.net/fileshare /monsoondrive/central -o vers=3.0,uid=$(id -u),file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/path/to/my/credentials.cred,serverino,mfsymlinks,user_xattr
```

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10851#issuecomment-484907843